# There is a way to disable MySQL client auto rehash option by default?

Tags: mysql

I have some local databases that contain lots of tables. I don't use the client's auto-complete feature, so I usually disable the auto rehash option. That makes the program loads faster. However, I forgot to add the `-A` when calling it. I was wondering if there is a way to set it by default without having to recompile it, perhaps through some config file. Is that possible?

I couldn't find anything related to that in the official docs, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
[mysql]
skip_auto_rehash
```

to your config.

Or you can alias `mysql` to `mysql -A` at bash level by putting this in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias mysql='mysql -A'
```

Comment: I created a file at `~/.my.cnf` with that entry you suggested and it worked.

Comment: After using this setting for a while, I found out it doesn't work with `mysqldump` -- it's no needed actually -- then I change `.my.cnf` to have `[mysql]` instead of `[client]`.